# How to connect to localhost in Docker in Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, localhost, containers

Background:

- Am using Windows Server 2016
- Have installed Containers
- Have installed Docker (not Docker Desktop / Docker for Windows): https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/
- Have multiple containers running on the same server
- I need container A to be able to connect to container B (on the same server)

What works:

- Hard coding the public IP address, container A can call via HTTP container B

What doesn't work

- Container A tries to use localhost to call over HTTP to container B
- Have also tried host.docker.internal which absolutely does not work.

What is the best way to do this?  I cannot hard code the IP address because the IP address of this server is dynamic on restart, hence why I would like to use something close to localhost.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with the network that your server has a dynamic IP address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is the default server configuration in Microsoft Azure